# Merge object with same key to one object and concatenate subarrays content

Tags: javascript

I have the following objects array, how can I merge the objects that have the same key (`ID`) to one object and concatenate the content of the subarrays (`Names`)?

```
var arr= [
    {ID: "A", Age: 1, Names: [1, 2]},
    {ID: "B", Age: 2, Names: [3, 4]},
    {ID: "C", Age: 3, Names: [5, 6]},
    {ID: "A", Age: 4, Names: [7, 8]},
]
```

Expected result:

```
var arr= [
    {ID: "A", Age: 1, Names: [1, 2, 7, 8]},
    {ID: "B", Age: 2, Names: [3, 4]},
    {ID: "C", Age: 3, Names: [5, 6]},
]
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] showing your attempt at solving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to group object by `ID`, and `Object.values` method to get array.

```js
var arr= [{ID: "A", Age: 1, Names: [1, 2]},{ID: "B", Age: 2, Names: [3, 4]},{ID: "C", Age: 3, Names: [5, 6]},{ID: "A", Age: 4, Names: [7, 8]}]

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r, e) => {
  if (!r[e.ID]) r[e.ID] = { ...e, Names: [...e.Names]}
  else r[e.ID].Names.push(...e.Names);
  return r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A quite simple grouping using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  {ID: 'A', Names: [1]},
  {ID: 'B', Names: [1]},
  {ID: 'C', Names: [1, 2]},
  {ID: 'A', Names: [3, 4]}
];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((a, b) => a.set(b.ID, (a.get(b.ID) || []).concat(b.Names)), new Map()))
  .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(res);
```